# Error #1067 - Invalid default value for 'updated_at'

Tags: sql, mysql

I try to import mysql file with phpmyadmin and face this error:

Error
SQL query: Copy

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `clan`

```sql
CREATE TABLE `clan` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `main_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `assist_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT '',
  `alert` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `coin` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `exp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `box` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `open_dun` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `use_card` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `reg_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `log` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `than_thu` text DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

#1067 - Invalid default value for 'updated_at'

This is my docker-compose.yaml file:

```yaml
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - game_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      mysql_phpmyadmin:
        aliases:
          - mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 300M
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      mysql_phpmyadmin:
        aliases:
          - phpmyadmin

networks:
  mysql_phpmyadmin:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  game_data:
```

It should have been imported normally, because I've imported many time use phpadmin on XAMPP.
First time I use docker, maybe some error in my config?

Comment: What versions of MySQL are you using? For example, in MySQL 5.7 and < 8.0.13 the following statement will fail: `... \`reg_date\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),\`updated_at\` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ...` but in MySQL >= 8.0.13 the following statement will work: `... \`reg_date\` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),\`updated_at\` date NOT NULL DEFAULT (current_timestamp()) ...`. Perhaps you were previously importing the data over MariaDB (another product other than MySQL)?

Comment: Thank you so much @wchiquito , I have changed mysql to mariadb and it has imported perfectly. I didn't realize before that the database I was using on XAMPP was actually MariaDB, the XAMPP control panel displayed "Start MySQL" and I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

Your `updated_at` column is a `date` type but default value is a `datetime`/`timestamp`.

The default value is not compatible with this type of column.

Comment: this sql file was exported before and I imported it many time without error on XAMPP, maybe it's ignored this error?

Comment: In recent versions of MySQL (MySQL >= 8.0.13), the syntax and behavior has changed, see [11.6 Data Type Default Values :: Explicit Default Handling as of MySQL 8.0.13](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html#data-type-defaults-explicit) and [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1mD4W9WA).